# Lsqnonlin on Matlab and Hardware-In-The-Loop with Arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino

I'm having some trouble with the function "lsqnonlin" on Matlab. I'm trying to optimize a PID controller inside Arduino by using this function that has the coefficients (Kp,Ki,Kd) of the PID as decisional variables and the goal function is to minimize the least-square difference of the response minus the reference value.

This link explains better what I'm doing: http://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin-with-a-simulink-model.html.

The difference between that example and my problem is that I want to perform a sort of Hardware-In-The-Loop simulation, replacing the simulation performed by Simulink with the actual system that I designed, on which a sensor interfaced with Arduino provides the response "yout" to Matlab by Serial Communication.

The problem is that the algorithm on Matlab changes the variables (Kp,Ki,Kd) with a really small step (10^-8 or something like that) and so I can't see any change on the actual response. After a few iterations the algorithm stops saying: "lsqnonlin stopped because the size of the current step is less than
the selected value of the step size tolerance".

I can't understand why the steps are so little and why it stops like that. My code is the following.

```
pid0 = [10 0 0]; %inizialization of PID parameters
options = optimset('LargeScale','off','Display','iter',...
       'TolX',0.001,'TolFun',0.001);
pid = lsqnonlin(@trackpid, pid0, [0 0 0], [], options) 
Kp = pid(1); Ki = pid(2); Kd = pid(3);
```

The trackpid function is:

```
function F = trackpid(pid)

% Serial communication
s = serial('/dev/cu.usbmodemFD131');
set(s,'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s,'DataBits', 8);
set(s,'StopBits', 1);

% Global Variables
numberOfDatas = 700;
Kp = pid(1)
Ki = pid(2)
Kd = pid(3)
i = 1; 

fopen(s); 

pause(1.7); %i need to wait 1.7s in order to read the values

%Send to Arduino the PID coefficients
fprintf(s,num2str(Kp));
fprintf(s,num2str(Ki));
fprintf(s,num2str(Kd));

while (fscanf(s,'%c') ~= 't') %Wait for Arduino to start the simulation
end

%Scan
while(i <= numberOfDatas) 
    yout(i) = fscanf(s,'%f');
    i = i + 1;
end

fclose(s); 

yout

F = yout - 21; %evaluate the difference between the response and the reference
```

Thank you in advance.